# Select records of week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written this query that gives me records of current day

```
SELECT EnquiryOwner,Count(uid) 
FROM EnquiryMaster 
WHERE orgid = '" + orgid + "' 
    AND (DAY(date) = DAY(GETDATE()) 
    AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
    AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(GETDATE())) 
GROUP BY EnquiryOwner
```

I want to select records of the week. if i accesss on tuesday i want the records from previous tuesday till this tuesday

Answer (score 3):

[You can use dateadd to determine the date of one week before.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258267%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

E.g. like

```
DAY(date)   = DATEADD(day,   -7, GETDATE()) AND    
MONTH(date) = DATEADD(month, -7, GETDATE()) AND
YEAR(date)  = DATEADD(year,  -7, GETDATE())
```

or

```
... WHERE date between DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

See also the list of [date and time functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you do not care about the time:

```
WHERE date between DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL 7 DAY) and DATE(NOW())
```

If you do care about the time:

```
WHERE date between DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) and NOW()
```

This is MYSQL. For SQL Server it would look like this:

```
WHERE date between DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

(I do not have sql server installed, so it is not tested.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hop one week before you just need to compare one date minus 7 using dateadd.

```
SELECT EnquiryOwner,Count(uid) 
FROM EnquiryMaster 
WHERE orgid = '" + orgid + "' 
    AND date = DATEADD(date, -7, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY EnquiryOwner
```